# How do I install compiz "window rules"?

Tags: compiz

at some point in time I discovered the "window rules" plugin within the compiz config manager. One can use that to automatically show some special application on every workspace for example (so instead of each time "click window title, select 'always on visible workspace' ... you could write down a rule to do it for you).

Now; with a fresh installation of 12.10 ... there are no more "window rules" within the compiz config manager.

Anyone aware of other ways to achieve similar behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins`

This will put back the plugins your used to. There compiz plugins that are not officially supported.